# Elastic scrolling like the Flowhome

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, scroll, android-animation

I found a new app which is still in beta i.e **Flowhome**. The menu drawer of that app had me amazed. It has a **beautiful scroll effect**. The apps are in a gridview and it feels like onscroll each gridview items respond to my finger. I spend a whole day researching on how to get that effect but could not find it. So my question is can anyone explain me how did they achieve that effect?

The Link to the app-  [Flowhome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.larvalabs.flow)

### **When it is still i.e no scroll takes place**

[image: When it is still i.e no scroll takes place]

### **This type of effct on scroll. I touched google keyboard and then swiped up, thus the rows adjacent to google keyboard has more effect than the items faraway from it.**

[image: This type of effct on scroll]

Comment: you achieved this?